# Why is this solution to Knight probability in chessboard wrong?

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

The problem statement from leetcode - https://leetcode.com/problems/knight-probability-in-chessboard/

Basically, knight starts from a given position and randomly picks 1 of 8 possible moves. It makes k such moves and we need to find the probability that it ends up staying on the board at the end of k moves. It is uniformly distributed, so each move has probability 1/8;

My approach -

Let us imagine a hypothetical case with no cycles and 2 valid moves at each depth. It will make a tree like this-

[tree of moves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46U4H.png)

So the probability will be

```
 (1/8 * (prob(b) + prob(c)) where prob(b) and prob(c) each = 1/8 * (sum of children)
```

In essence, (1/8)^k * number of leaf nodes.

Now we take into account the cycles and memoization for those cycles -
If for any given node x, we have come looking for depth k, then the leaf nodes at the end of that search will contribute

`(1/8) ^ (k - kOfX)`.

So for example, if the image of the above tree actually represented a subtree in a bigger tree then we could imagine coming to A with k = 1 as part of some cycle instead of k = 2. While calculating for k = 2, we could use the depth difference between parent and child to calculate the contribution the child makes for each of its parents. So direct children would contributr (1/8)^(k - (k -1)) =  1/8. Whenever we visit a node, we update all of its parents using this formula.

the code -

```
public class KnightProbabilityInChessboard {
    class Pair{
        int row, col;
        int k;
        Pair(int row, int col, int k){
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
            this.k = k;
        }

        Pair(int row, int col){
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
        }
    }
    //Flow starts from here. This is the execution point
    public double knightProbability(int n, int k, int row, int column) {
        int isVisited[][] = new int[n][n];
        double value[][][] = new double[n][n][k + 1];
        knightProbabilitycalc2(k , value, isVisited, row, column, new ArrayList<>());
        return value[row][column][k];
    }

    //main logic
    void knightProbabilitycalc2(int k, double value[][][], int visited[][], int row, int column, List<Pair> parents) {

         //memozied block. IF a node is visited we store the depth of pre existing calculation
        if (visited[row][column] > k && k!= 0) {
            for(int i = parents.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i){
                Pair parent = parents.get(i);
                double res =  Math.pow((1/8.0), parent.k - k - 1) * value[row][column][k];
                value[parent.row][parent.col][parent.k - k] += res;
            }
            return;
        }

        //if not the last move in sequence then search deeper
        if(k != 0) {
            int n = value.length;
            List<Pair> validMoves = getAllMoves(row, column).stream().filter((move) -> isValid(move.row, move.col, n - 1, n - 1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            parents.add(new Pair(row, column, k));
            for (Pair move : validMoves) {
                knightProbabilitycalc2(k - 1, value, visited, move.row, move.col, parents);
            }
            parents.remove(parents.size() - 1);
        }

        //after search is over, update all of its parents using the aforementioned forumla
        for(int i = parents.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i){
            Pair parent = parents.get(i);
            double res =  Math.pow((1/8.0), parent.k - k);
            value[parent.row][parent.col][parent.k - k] += res;
        }
        // all possible values of values[row][column][index<=k] have been calculated.
        visited[row][column] = k;
    }


    List<Pair> getAllMoves(int row, int col){
        List<Pair> validMoves = new ArrayList<>();
        validMoves.add(new Pair(row - 2, col - 1));
        validMoves.add(new Pair(row - 2, col + 1));
        validMoves.add(new Pair(row + 2, col + 1));
        validMoves.add(new Pair(row + 2, col - 1));
        validMoves.add(new Pair(row + 1, col - 2));
        validMoves.add(new Pair(row + 1, col + 2));
        validMoves.add(new Pair(row - 1, col - 2));
        validMoves.add(new Pair(row - 1, col + 2));
        return validMoves;
    }

    boolean isValid(int r, int c, int maxR, int maxC){
        return (0 <= r &&  r <= maxR  && 0 <= c && c <= maxC);
    }
```

This code works for till k = 3 for various values of n but fails from 4 and onwards for simple cases. I suspect this is because of the logic of cycles. Also, it underestimates the results by a lot. For k = 30, n = 8 the expected output is 0.0019 while mine gives e-25 scale output.

I can confirm that move generation and validity checks are fine. It works for all cases k <= 3

I know there are bottom up approaches but I want to understand why this doesn't work. This is why I feel it is different from the other SO questions about this specific problem. It focuses on implementation difficulties.